# Visual Studio 2012 CREATE DATABASE denied in database 'master'

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I installed Visual Studio 2012.. but I noticed that it hasn't installed SQL Server. So when I try to create a database and add a connection and then test a connection, it tells me that I have an error that has to do with a failure to connect to a remote source.

So what are my options to install a SQL Server? Or is there any other option to create a database?

UPDATE:

I got to access.. but I get:

> *CREATE DATABASE denied in database 'master'*

Comment: _it tells me that i have an error that has to do with a failure to connect to a remote source_ This is a really precise error description!

Comment: SQL Network Interfaces, error 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

Comment: Well I use Visual Studio 2012 premium without any problems. Only with Windows 8 can there problems when looking up network-names. Swapping to IP addesses can solve this. But I am not sure if this helps you.

Comment: I think it is because I have no sql express installed with this edition but i do remember that 2010 had sql express installed in it .. can it be a reason..do I need to install sql express 2005 by myself?

Comment: Well, if you have set up a whole new system that would be the reason :) I mean you must be able to choose a existing instance and DB where you want to connect to

Comment: Whats teh difference between connecting to sql server and creating mdf file and using it (basically attaching a new database file)?

Comment: A mdf is runned by a service that normally maintains the connection to it like the SQL server service. So when connection to a Database runned by the SQL server you connect to a mdf. The other variant would be a sdf which is just locally accessible.

Comment: I installed SQL server 2005 now.. How do I connect between vs2012 and that server?

Comment: it gives me CREATE DATABASE denied in database 'master'.. how do I avoid it?

Comment: Are you kidding me? Well I guess MS stays backward compatible, so simply add one of your preferred data connections to a existing project like ADO.Net, EF or LINQ to SQL. That ould be the simplest way

Comment: So, this is my **last comment**: Check your access. I guess your user is not registered as server admin within the SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Okay solved it. had to install sql management studio 2005 and run it as an administrator, then create a database there... damn, windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2012 does install SQL Express, however it installs as (localdb)\v11.0 rather than the traditional .\sqlexpress.  Take a look and see if you can connect to the localdb instance.  This is a developer focused version of SQL Express.

For more information, take a look at this:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx